# stepping with gdb seems to show program statements not having any effect

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, stdvector

I have a struct that is declared on the stack. Here is what the struct looks like:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int integer;
    std::vector<bool > booleanVector;
};
```

When I step through the following function with gdb, printing the value of `s.integer` and `s.booleanVector.size()`, the statements seem to have no effect.

```
MyStruct getMyStruct()
{
    MyStruct s;   
    s.integer = 3;
    s.booleanVector.resize( s.integer );
    return s;
}
```

However, when I insert print statements such as `std::cout << s.integer << std::endl;` the output shows that the values of `s.integer` and `s.booleanVector.size()` have been properly changed.

I discovered that the problem seems to be associated with the struct being returned by the function in which it is declared. The problem with gdb displaying invalid information about the struct does not occur if it is not being returned by the function in which it is declared.

This is a simplified example that exhibits a problem I had while attempting to debug a project. This problem with gdb was distracting me from an actual error in my code and making it difficult to find (originally I thought the problem might be a subtle bug in my code, which is why I posted it here). [Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14341677/gdb_confusion.cpp) is a complete small program that exhibits this behaviour on my system.

I guess my question is if this is just a bug with gdb or does this behaviour occur as a result of how gcc handles structs / classes that are to be returned from a function.

Note: Using gdb 6.3 with gcc 4.2 in Mac OSX 10.6 (Snow Leopard)

Comment: Could you try to provide a minimal compilable example that reproduces this behavior?

Comment: Could you add more information about the struct you use: How it is declared, how is it initialized...

Comment: @Mat I added an example and mostly answered my own question if you are interested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This debugging issue is fixed by upgrading to a more recent version of gcc. When the code is compiled with gcc 4.7, gdb displays correct information about the struct.

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in GCC (see link below).

This also happens while using the following GDB version:

> i686-apple-darwin9-g++-4.0.1 (GCC) 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)
>   Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

... and even when compiling with -O0

Here is the link to the full bug tracker on the GCC project:

http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44731

The programs produced are correctly-running programs.  The problem was entirely related to optimizations having an effect even with the build set as 'zero optimizations,' and to improper debug info placed into the binary by gcc.